# Including new header file to standard library in C++

Tags: c++, compilation, header-files

I wrote a simple C++ program to parse an XML string, called sample.cpp. The program includes a header file, tinyxml.h. When I compiled the program on a unix machine I got the error:

```
 tinyxml.h: No such file or directory
```

How can we add new header files to the standard library and make them compile? Can anyone please help to get it done? Thank you

Comment: You need to tell your compiler where to look for the header file. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: You don't add headers to the standard library. Though that doesn't actually appear to be what you're trying to do.

Comment: Funny to note, that nowadays people post in forums on how to include a header file. Where are we heading. :-)

Comment: Sorry to tell you Sujay....I didn't really mean 'how to include a header file 'into one program.I thought what i really meant will be conveyed well through my question.Felt sad to get a response like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell your compiler where to find the header file. This depends on the compiler, but is typically done by specifying `-I<directory>` on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

If the header file is in the same directory as the cpp file, you need to include it in quotes, instead of angle brackets, ie.

```
#include "tinyxml.h"
```

Instead of

```
#include <tinyxml.h>
```

Comment: The standard is silent on this. The behavior is compiler specific